# Direct different users to different databases at login

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, dynamic, database-connection

I need to have different connection strings for different users. There are several threads which present similar scenarios, none of which have the solution -- how to establish a dynamic connection to a database for a user at login.

I've gotten as far as being able to dynamically get the connection string, but not quite sure what to do to set it/them (and keep different strings active for different users).

I have a ClientDbContext Model in which I have

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{    public class ClientDbContext : DbContext
            {
    public ClientDbContext(string DefaultConnection)
                  : base("DefaultConnection")
{
}
```

In my ClientController

```
using MyProject.Models;

    namespace MyProject.Controllers
    {
        public class ClientController : Controller
        {
            private ClientDbContext db = new ClientDbContext("DefaultConnection");
```

Big picture here.... The goal is to dynamically set a connection to a specific database (catalog) when a user logs in. There could be several dozen different databases.

Process (currently working :-))

1. User gets login page (Account).
2. Enters login information (Account).
3. Login controller (Account) checks for valid entry; matches
   user-entered string to a previously entered string in the user
       profile; and matches user entered string to expected name of
       database (in a dbStrings table).

I can retrieve a specific database name and string for the user during login. I created a temp error message to show me the name and string.

What should happen next...

**The selected string should be used to create a db connection for the user. 
I'm stuck on this ....**

Then, the user is redirected to the Index for Clients (Clients) -- this is working

**and the selected connection remains for the user (until the user closes the browser or logs out - ends the session). 
Not quite sure how to set this....**

Other users could log in with different credentials. The system has to keep the connections discrete for each authenticated user.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/958540

Comment: @Scott... not quite the same. That was one of the posts I reviewed. Setting up classes for 50+ strings is not feasible. The 'get from db' solution was one I'd seen here. It's the best of the lot. But there was nothing that addressed the specific error message --- it was more a theory/strategy approach.

Comment: _Which gives an error "The name "DefaultConnection" does not exist in the current context. This seems to be one of the recommended solutions. What am I missing that it's not working?_  duh... quotes         'private ClientDbContext db = new ClientDbContext("DefaultConnection");' Still looking for how to set the connection.

Comment: @Terri - Are the database names in any way related to the username entered?

Comment: Yes. I have a UserProfile table that is used for authentication (Identity). It includes a value for DbID (FK) on my DataStrings table. When the user is registered (admin function) there is a dropdown list for selecting the DB to which the user will have access. It takes the DbID (PK) from my DataStrings table to display the name of the DB. I am checking 1.user entry 2. user table and 3. data strings table for a match during login (along with user name and password). When all 3 match, I get the associated connection string (DbID - DataStrings). Up to this point, I have it working.

Comment: if (userDB == user.DbList.DbName).... more .....  'ModelState.AddModelError("", "Score! valid database name. Your Db connection is... " + userDB + user.DbList.DbName + conn);' My error message shows me the values -- correctly. Now, what to do with them???